# How to set background when using this frame switching method

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am using this method of frame switching for menus: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter). I don't know how I can set a background when using this, since I'm never making a window in a variable. I tried using window manager (wm), but it doesn't have any background functionality. Only geometry, and icon. I also tried to set a label with an image to hopefully get a background. Nothing worked. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do. "making a window in a variable" is irrelevant. They are all just normal frame widgets.

For example, if you want `PageOne` to have a background image you can use `place` to create the image before creating the other widgets on that page. By using `place`, the placement of the image won't affect the placement or size of any other widgets.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # create a background image for this page
        self._background_image = tk.PhotoImage(...)
        bglabel = tk.Label(self, image=self._background_image)
        bglabel.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

        ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the self.controller = controller